# Module Config File: what are resource connection definitions for

Tags: database, module, magento-1, configuration

I searched for that information quite a while but did not found any explanation.

Many examples and tutorials for custom modules with custom database tables suggest the following for the config.xml file of corresponding module:

```
<resources>
    <[modulename]_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>[NAMESPACE]_[MODULENAME]</module>
            <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
    </[modulename]_setup>
    <[modulename]_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
    </[modulename]_write>
    <[modulename]_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
    </[modulename]_read>
</resources>
```

So my questions are:

1. What are `[modulename]_write` and `[modulename]_read` for?
2. What is the connection definition in `[modulename]_setup` for?
3. What is `<class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>` for?

I ask this, because it works well with just

```
<resources>
    <[modulename]_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>[NAMESPACE]_[MODULENAME]</module>
        </setup>
    </[modulename]_setup>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<[modulename]_write>` and `<[modulename]_read>` db resources are no longer required since Magento 1.4. Configuring them does no harm however, the `core/resource` class automatically falls back to the `default_*` set of db resources.
I guess most people still put them there because they follow old blog posts. The only valid reason would be if indeed a custom db connection would be configured, different from the default one, or to have your module support ancient Magento instances.

The `<[modulename]_setup>` resource is for using setup scripts with your module. The `<class>` node defines the PHP class that will execute the setup scripts found in *sql/* or *data/*.
If the `<class>` node is omitted, the default setup class `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup` is used.